# How to set MAMP to use existing MySQL on OS X SL?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm running on a zero-config environment. I installed Ruby, then MySQL, etc.

Now, I'm using PHP, so I installed MAMP PRO and see it also includes MySQL.

I thought that I could have MAMP use the same MySQL that I was already using on OS X.

I tried to change the MySQL port to the default `3306`, but it didn't work as expected.

How can I let MAMP access the existing MySQL that I have?

Comment: Try Xampp, it's so much better.

Comment: and could i to set its mysql the previous mysql i have?

Answer (score 1):

As this is an old post, slight changes to paths between MAMP versions may require some slight adjusting to this answer, though the same process will work in all MAMP/MAMP PRO versions:

- Click the Ports tab in the Preferences panel and set your MySQL port to what your existing MySQL configuration is set to (`3306` in the OP's case):

[image: MAMP MySQL port change]

- MAMP will restart and you will notice the green status light isn't lit up. Open up your Finder and navigate to the MAMP configuration directory, which should be similar to the following if you chose the default installation:

`cd /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5`

- open the `php5.ini` file in a text editor find the following line:

`mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

- Change it to the default location of your MySQL socket, ie:

`mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock`

- If you stop and start MAMP, you should now be able to work with your original MySQL databases. Note that MAMP will now display that MySQL is stopped, because it really doesn't think MySQL is started:

[image: MAMP status]

This answer was largely referenced from [this site](http://v2.scriptplayground.com/tutorials/mysql/Configuring-MAMP-on-OS-X-to-use-default-settings/).